# Change of folder path when require/ include an php file

Tags: php, include, require, include-path, server-side-includes

I am currently using an index.php to include another file , it structure like:

```
root / index.php
     / new/ index.php
          / img/ test.jpg
```

And I write following in root/index.php :

```
<?php
require_once("new/index.php");
?>
```

the problem is , all paths in it are wrong. As all paths are based on new/index.php.

For example, In new/index.php my test.jpg is like

```
<img src="img/test.jpg" />
```

It shows `http://www.test.com/new/img/test.jpg` when I directly access new/index.php

But it shows `http://www.test.com/img/test.jpg` when I include the php in index.php.

How to fix it? I tried chdir() but it does not work expect Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use the required / included file as base directory in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161253/use-the-required-included-file-as-base-directory-in-php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you always include with an absolute path, like:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/otherfile.php");
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../uponefolder.php");
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/sub/folder/file.php");
```

Or use autoloading.

Comment: thanks for your help , when I open the index.php the image file is still broken

Comment: Shows http://www.test.com/img/test.jpg but actually is in http://www.test.com/new/img/test.jpg

Comment: How are you generating the path?

Comment: Turn it into an absolute (web)path.

Comment: but when I include new/index.php in index.php , it will be img/test.jpg instead of new/img/test.jpg

Comment: since there are a lots of files and line affected, are there any easier way? thanks

Comment: Probably, but it wont be pretty.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it seems the problem can not be sloved in one or two line of codes

Answer (score 2):

Did you just ask the same question twice? [Use the required / included file as base directory in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161253/use-the-required-included-file-as-base-directory-in-php/19162444#19162444)

See my answer there.

Answer (score 1):

The folder path you have in the require_once() function is relative to the directory your page is currently in.  Have a look at the [set_include_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) function.  Specifically, you could add that function to the top of your scripts to set the root include folder.  Something like this:

```
set_include_path("/var/www/html/root");
require_once("new/index.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply change the included HTML document base by adding a **base** tag.
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

```
<head>
  <base href="your_new_url_base" target="_blank">
</head>
```

The HTML included file could check "Am I included from a parent?" if so "I have to change my base tag"...

```
// new/index.php

echo '<head>';

if (basename(__FILE__) == basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"])) {
  // called directly, no need base tag;
} else {
  // included/required
  echo '<base href="your_new_url_base" target="_blank">';
}

echo '</head>';
```