# Php includes between 2 subdirectories

Tags: php

I have

> ```
> public_html/dir/dir1/1.php and
> public_html/dir/dir2/2.php
> ```

how to include 1.php into 2.php?

DETAILS:
I have 2 file as 
    public_html/projectplay/functions/functions.php
And 
    public_html/projectplay/includes/header.php

And also,
    public_html/projectplay/includes/header_pc.php
    public_html/projectplay/includes/header_mob.php

In header.php, I must include functions.php
I tried bellow code

```
<?php 
require '../functions/functions.php';
if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {
include 'header_mob.php';

}
else {
include 'header_pc.php';
}

?>
```

ANd my 
    public_html/projectplay/index.php is here

```
<?php require_once 'functions/functions.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php include 'includes/header.php';?>
Dummy Dummy Dymmy
<?php include 'includes/footer.php';?>
```

And public_html/projectplay/includes/footer.php  is

But it output an error on index.php

> Warning: require(../functions/functions.php): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in
>   /home/epdroidc/public_html/projectplay/includes/header.php on line 2
>
> Warning: require(../functions/functions.php): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in
>   /home/epdroidc/public_html/projectplay/includes/header.php on line 2
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '../functions/functions.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in
>   /home/epdroidc/public_html/projectplay/includes/header.php on line 2

Where is my problem? I am new in php.

Comment: Just remove the `require '../functions/functions.php';` in `header.php` because you're including it within `index.php`.

Comment: But what if i want to use header.php in public_html/files/index.php (or anything new file that have not <?php require_once 'functions/functions.php'; ?>) ? then how header.php load functions.php.? I got an idea! better remove <?php require_once 'functions/functions.php'; ?> from index.php

Comment: No. Every file you include has access to all php variables and functions that you have previously declared or included. So require_once in the index.php is a better practice.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute instead of relative paths. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162434/change-of-folder-path-when-require-include-an-php-file) for reference.

Note that it seems that in index.php you already require `functions/functions.php`. Your application logic occurs to be a bit chaotic.

Comment: It might be worthwhile noting to use `require_once`, as you'll probably get `cannot redeclare function previously declared` error.

Comment: I'll need functions.php in index.php later. I can add it using path functions/functions.php from root, index.php as an example but problem occurs while try it in different subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

in php2:

```
require_once('../dir1/php1.php');
```

or

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/public_html/dir/dir1/php1.php');
```

Comment: Warning: require_once(../dir1/php1.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/epdroidc/public_html/projectplay/dir2/2.php on line 1

Comment: 1.php have "blaaaaaaa blaaaaaaaaa" and 2.php have <?php require_once('../dir1/php1.php'); ?>